# Multiple popovers for different buttons with same Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overlay, react-bootstrap, popover

I have a table with a STATUS column, so whenever the status has an error value I need to display a popover onClick of error and close it with a close button inside the popover. Problem is when I click on first row error all the popovers for all the errors in the table appear and when I close one all of then closes. But I need the popover to open and close only on clicked error status. I am using react framework. Can someone please help me out?
Here is my popover code

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { popoverShow: false };
}

getTarget = () => {
    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.target);
};

handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ popoverShow: !this.state.popoverShow });
};

let installedDCToolTip = (
                    <Popover id="datacollector-error-message-popover"
                        className="netapp-help-inline__popover tw-mt-10px"
                    >
                        <PopoverDiv className="tw-leading-lg">
                            <span className="row tw-font-body tw-text-lg tw-inline-flex tw-justify-between" >Error
                            <button
                                    id="close-datacollector-error-popover"
                                    type="button"
                                    className="btn-icon-no-bg close"
                                    onClick={this.handleToggle}>
                                    <i className="oci-app oci-close"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            <hr className="tw-mb-sm" />
                            <div>{info.record.message}</div>
                            <a
                                id="datacollector-status-error-docs"
                                href={DATA_COLLECTOR_ERROR_HELP_DOC_URL}
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            >
                                Need Help?
                        </a>
                        </PopoverDiv>
                    </Popover>
                );
```

overlay

```
return (info.value === COLLECTOR_STATUS.ERROR || info.value === COLLECTOR_STATUS.RETRYING) ? 
 <button
                            id="datacollector-error-detail-button"
                            ref={button => {
                                this.target = button;
                            }}
                            onClick={this.handleToggle}
                        >
                            <span className="tw-text-hyperlink">Error Detail</span>
                        </button>
                        <Overlay {...sharedPropsForOverlay} placement="bottom">
                            {installedDCToolTip}
                        </Overlay>
                    </div>
                    
                    : <span>{_.startCase(_.capitalize(info.value))}</span>;

 render() {
        const sharedPropsForOverlay = {
            container: this,
            target: this.getTarget,
            show: this.state.popoverShow


           };
/* render table */

    }
```

Comment: can you please post whole components not just snippets of them , cause now I don't know which is which

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a self state for each row. For example

```
const YourRow = ()=>{
  
   const [popoverOpen, setPopOverOpen] = useState(false);
   const someActionThatChangeState = ()=>{
       setPopOverOpen(true);
   } 


   return <tr>

        ====================
        ====================
        <PopOver></PopOver>
        <SomeIconORButton reactEvent(onCick etc)={someActionThatChangeState} />
         </tr> //This is specific to your row you can change what ever you want
 }
```

Comment: Hi, the table component is used by other features also so I can’t really modify each row. Is there any work around using popover or overlay itself? Or can I use any other react or bootstrap component to achieve this feature?